# Xamarin Forms Flyout Page not showing in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin forms flyout page to make the settings page, it works fine like the image below but it does not show in iOS. This setting page is not the root page

Android:
[image]

iOs:
[image]

My flyout page is just a normal flyout out page was created from visual studio.

Flyout page:

[image]

app shell:

[image]

I don't know what happened, anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommend to use FlyoutPage inside shell, you can post an issue in github if you insist. However, you can use TabbedPage and FlyoutPage together instead.
like:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My_Forms_Test2.Views"
             x:Class="My_Forms_Test2.MainTabbedPage">
    <NavigationPage Title="Settings" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Page1/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <local:Page2/>
    <local:Page3/>
```

flyoutpage:

```
<FlyoutPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My_Forms_Test2.Views"
    x:Class="My_Forms_Test2.Views.Page1"
    Title="Settings">
 <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
     <local:MenuPage/>
 </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <local:Page2/>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I posted the issue on Github and thinking about used the tabpage instead